# How do I build just the directory containing my updated source code

Tags: android, kernel, gnu-make, device-driver, kbuild

I successfully created an image for Samsung Note 3 by downloading the source from Samsung and AOSP and running make as instructed in the README file. But now I want to modify a device driver, and see the result in the image. This means I really do not want to recreate an entire image; rather just the modified file, which is /drivers/char/examples directory. I have tried "m", "mm", and "mmm" but I get the following error:

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ m
m: command not found
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ mm
The program 'mm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install multimail
```

I have also tried to run make from the example directory and I get:

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY/drivers/char/examples$ make 
make --directory=src
make: *** src: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

Here is what I have in this directory as well as the make file:

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY/drivers/char/examples$ ls
backup  examples.c  hello1.c  Makefile
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY/drivers/char/examples$ more Makefile 
lib_src := src 
lib_headers := headers 
.PHONY: all $(lib_src) $(lib_headers)
$(lib_src) :
    $(MAKE) --directory=$@
    $(lib_*): $(MAKE) --directory=$@

obj-$(CONFIG_TOS)   += examples.o
```

What should I do so that when I update the c source file, I can build an updated image to flash my phone and try to see the result?

I wonder if I remove the examples.ko, make will rebuild again. The question is would this work if I issue make just for the /examples directory?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: 'mm' should build all modules in the current directory; it is installed in your current shell environment by calling build/envsetup.sh (http://elinux.org/Android_Build_System).  In order for it to build correctly, you may need to also set your target platform with 'lunch' or 'breakfast' (Cyanogenmod) commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot that is wrong here, so it is impossible to figure out what is supposed to happen. I'll just describe what's going on.

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY/drivers/char/examples$ make 
make --directory=src
make: *** src: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

means that the Makefile is expecting a directory called `src` to exist under the place where you run `make`. That directory should have a file called `Makefile` in it which will give further instructions for how to compile `examples.c` and `hello1.c`.

Let's say the `src` directory is under `~/WORKING_DIRECTORY`. In that case you would invoke make via `make -f drivers/char/examples`.

However I'm guessing that in that directory or one of the others, you should see the programs `m` or `mm` that I guess you were instructed to run. And I'm also guessing that this is what will issue that more unusual *make* command.